# Selenium RC (java)+ Safari3 + XP

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, safari, cross-browser, selenium-rc

I am using seleniumRc 1.0.3 version this is fine..I am good with IE and Firefox..This is very good.. But i want to test in other browsers like "Safari and Chrome".

I am not able to execute my script with Safari and Chrome browsers..

In my script i am using https in the URl then whenever it url loading it should give alert (modelwiondow / popup some one caling like these) for authentication details ( username and password).

I am successfully done with firefox and IE i have done one step manually...that is fine...

But i want to do in safari also.. Can any one help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the WebDriver extensions to test Safari and Chrome in Selenium:

- [WebKitDriver](http://code.google.com/p/webkitdriver/)(Headless Webkit)
- [SafariDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/safari/SafariDriver.html)(Safari)

**References**

- [SafariDriver Internals](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver-Internals)